# Javascript setTimeout call multiple time

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a one page horizontal sliding site. each slider has a question and a timer. when user slides to next, it should reset the timer and start from beginning. here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mytimer;
    $('#main').on('click', '.slidinglink', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var section = $(this).attr('href');
        var slide = $(this).data('slide');
        var left = '';

        if(section != '#'){
            $('.timer').show();
            left = '-100%';

            var $active_question = $('.answer-list.active');
            //mytimer = null;
            clearTimeout( mytimer );
            mytimer = setTimeout(function () {
                finish_question( $('.answer-list > li.checked') );
            }, 5000);

            do_sliding(left, section, slideback);
        }
    });

});
```

The timer works for the first time. but if i go to next section, the timer does not work. What seems to be the problem? I have 2 other setTimeout functions which are also called during slide. They are like this (both similar):

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    item.removeClass('clone');
}, 20);
```

Comment: Have you heard about http://jsfiddle.net/ ? If you could possibly make an example that demonstrates the problem, including some HTML markup, along with your javascript, it would help greatly in helping you find out what is happening in your case where your site is not working correctly. You could add a link to the fiddle in your question after saving it.

Comment: @Zack Why recommend Jsfiddle when Stack Overflow has equally capable fiddling capabilities built in?

Comment: I just wanted to know if my approach here was right. I cannot share the whole code, its huge. I think the example code I gave here is good enough to understand.

Comment: There seems to be no problems. If my interpretation is right the simplified version would be [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c4Lj0vu5/). If you click on all divs, from left to right it should show just *timed out 1* because it ran only 1 time. If you were to comment out the `clearTimeout` it will show the amount of divs you clicked with delays between clicks. So the real problem I presume is what you expect from the result and the other functions you have in your code

Comment: @Nit Very true. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: @Imrul.H You wouldn't be sharing your entire code, just enough to be able to reproduce the behavior you are describing. Without any HTML markup, anyone who wants to reproduce it would have to figure all that out, and it is just too much for many people that would otherwise be willing to help out with your question.